# Not able to pip install xlrd in virtual env

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have set up a virtual environment (`venv` in `projects` in `home` folder) and I need to install `xlrd` Python module. However, when I run the command

```
pip install xlrd
```

I get this error

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ajay/projects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/ajay/projects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 293, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/ajay/projects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 756, in build
    ensure_dir(output_dir)
  File "/home/ajay/projects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 70, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/home/ajay/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/home/ajay/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/home/ajay/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/home/ajay/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ajay/.cache/pip/wheels/42'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think it's a permission thing, you should give this library permissions.

Comment: `pip` should not require `sudo` permission in a virtual environment. I am wondering why does is need to use `'/home/ajay/.cache/pip/wheels/42'`?

Comment: Did you activate your virtual environment ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
sudo chown -R ajay:ajay /home/ajay/.cache
```